# Scraping texts with beautiful soup in python - why won't bulk addresses work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape more than 3000 websites with beautiful soup in python. My code worked for about 50 websites but will get stuck if I run 1000 or 3000+ at the same time.

It's odd that the code won't work for multiple websites, I'd like to get some advice on how to trouble shoot this. Is this normal, or is there another way around it?

When I run 1000, it won't deliver any results even after 6 or 7 hours so I suspect that the code is not working at all. I'd like to get some comments.

Code:

```
import csv
d = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv', 'rU'))

soc = []
for row in d:
    soc.append(row)

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

from bs4 import *
import time
import requests
import urllib2

# create lists
mega = []
mega2 = []
mega3 = []


for i in range(len(soc)): # all links, about 3000
    myurl = soc[i]['report_url']
    try:
        html = urllib2.urlopen(myurl).read()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, error: 
        continue
    except urllib2.URLError, error:
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    row = soup.findAll('tr')
    for r in row:
        mega.append([r.get_text()]) # force all raw text into a list in list
        mega2 = [x[0] for x in mega]
    mega3.append(mega2)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Have you check if you  are being blocked  by your IPS or their CDN / Firewall?

Comment: Add some print statements to see where it gets stuck. One way would be to add one between each line and just let them print out 1 to ...n

Comment: @Lexxxxx Could you be more specific? How can I tell python to print where it gets stuck?

Comment: In your first for loop add `print(1)`, `print(2)`, `print(3)`, etc.. after each line (considering correct indents of course). This way the console will show output (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3) and you can see where in the code it stops running. Maybe also `print(myurl)` as @BoarGules specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code works for 50 websites then there are two possibilities:
(1) There is a link in your list that has data that isn't what the code expects.
(2) You are running out of resources.
Have the program report the link that it is about to scan and a timestamp.
If the output just stops then the last link is the problem. If the timestamps get further and further apart then resources are the probelm.

Comment: I found a way to print the link and the timestamp, it seems that approximate time for scraping is 5 seconds.

Comment: Is there a way to force the code to stop if the time takes too long? for instance I can add something like, stop if time takes more than 15 seconds for a link.

Comment: You can set a timeout on urlopen(). `html = urllib2.urlopen(myurl, timeout=5).read()`